# Combining different tidymodels-outcomes

Tags: r, glm, tidymodels

I've developped a glm-model and a random-forest on the same data with Tidymodels (classification).

Would it be useful to optimize these models by comparing the predictions-weights ("probs", I think in caret) where rf and glm divert? So, if glm-pos > rf-neg the outcome is glm, else rf?

And if so, would it be valid to optimize the outcome by correcting the probs with the accuratesse-factor?

Comment: you may be interested in the [stacks](https://stacks.tidymodels.org/) package --- you can feed the predictions from multiple models as inputs to a larger meta-model and potentially get better predictions. I believe it uses `{glmnet}` for the larger model, so stacks will penalize models that are weaker predictors.